# VS 2010: Call Stack says: [external code] and won't show calling code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I can't see what code called the line being executed at runtime using the debugger.

[image]

**Added:** How do I step into the methods that called the code being exectued themselves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

- Right click on the call stack
- Select "Show External Code"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I can't see the actual methods.. just kind of code I don't know (Disassembly) that looks like that:  00000094  pop ebx .

Comment: @Oren A, it sounds like you either don't have symbols for those methods, it's native code or you don't have source code for the methods.  It sounds like the source code issue because in the abscence of source code and symbols it will just display dissasembly.  There isn't a way to fix this other than providing the source code.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I don't have the source code.. Was sure the calling code was mine but it's not. Thanks.